# spl_autoloader: Limit scope

Tags: php, wordpress, autoload, spl-autoload-register

If I get the behaviour of **SPL Autoloader** correctly, it acts in a "global scope", right? If we have, say, this code:

```
class Autoloader {

    protected static $instance = NULL;

    public static function get_instance() {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function init() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'autoload'));
    }

    private function autoload() {
        // to the autoload magic
    }

}

$autoloader = new Autoloader();
$autoloader->init();

// or

add_action('muplugins_loaded', array(Autoloader::get_instance(),'init'));
```

... it applies to the rest of the application OR if hooked to Wordpress action, from the hook onwards, right?

It just seems to me that it is not very convenient, especially if you work in the frame of larger frameworks (such as Wordpress). Is there way, how to limit the scope of SPL Autoload to specific context by:

1. defining the SPL Autoload different way?
2. having something specific in the function (such as `return false` on e.g. classes which names does not much some sort of pattern)?
3. **something more clever?**

I know, that I can add some conditional statements to `autoload()` function to avoid conflicts and errors, it just does not seem very efficient.

Thanks! And yes, it is very possible that I'm just overlooking something.

### Edit

**Mimicing directory structure by namespaces**: It's not actually possible within Wordpress, is it? If what you're after is some sort of communication and logical structure between, say, **must-use plugins** and **themes**. (@RoyalBg)

**Not finding a file**: How to determine than when it is "okay" to not finding a file and when it is not? By logic of the function? It still seems to me, that reducing the scope of autoloader would be way more elegant sollution. (@Jon, @Mark Baker)

But if I understand your comments well, SPL Autoloader truly applies "globally" by default.

Comment: For `3.` yes, there are namespaces :-)

Comment: 2 applies as well, if there are multiple autoloaders in an app, then PHP will loop through all nested autoloaders until a non false return from the autoload magic

Comment: @RoyalBg: Can you elaborate and/or give a simple example? I am trying to wrap my head around namespaces too and Wordpress does not make it easy for me. :)

Comment: Not sure what you are after here. You can register as many autoloaders as you want and as long as all of them are well-behaved, they can simply do nothing if they don't want to handle a specific class. PHP will automatically try each autoloader in turn until one of them loads the class.

Comment: @PetrCibulka I don't know what your actual problem is, in order to give an example, but if your classes are well defined with namespaces, which resolve a directory structure, you will never load the wrong class, and you will work in the scope of the directory tree the current namespace is.

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple autoloader function/methods. SPL will go through them all until the desired class is loaded.

```
<?php
function loaderA($name) { // Do Stuff }
function loaderB($name) { // Do Other Stuff }
spl_autoload_register('functionA');
spl_autoload_register('functionB');
?>
```

SPL will go through these registered functions, one after the other. At first functionA, then functionB, if the requested class is not loaded via functionA.

EDIT:

```
final class LoaderException extends \Exception{}

class Loader {

    /**
     * Project-Root-Directory
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $AbsPath;
    /**
     * Directory-List
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $DirList;

    /**
     * DO NOT INSTANTIATE
     */
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * The actual autoloader.
     * @param string $name Class-Name
     * @return void
     * @throws LoaderException
     */
    public static function load($name) {
        if(!is_string($name))
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument is not a string.');
        $a = isset(static::$AbsPath) ? static::$AbsPath : '';
        $f = str_replace('\\', '/', $name).'.php';
        if(!is_array(static::$DirList)) {
            if(file_exists($a.$f))
                return include $a.$f;
            if(file_exists(getcwd().$f))
                return include getcwd().$f;
            throw new LoaderException('Unable to load "'.$name.'".');
        }
        foreach(static::$DirList as $d) {
            if(file_exists($a.$d.$f))
                return include $a.$d.$f;
        }
        throw new LoaderException('Unable to load "'.$name.'".');
    }

    /**
     * Registers the Loader.
     */
    public static function register() {
        spl_autoload_register(__CLASS__.'::load');
    }

    /**
     * Unregisters the Loader.
     */
    public static function unregister() {
        spl_autoload_unregister(__CLASS__.'::load');
    }

    /**
     * Adds one, or more, directories to the Directory-List.
     * @throws LoaderException
     */
    public static function addDir() {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $k => $v) {
            if(!is_string($v))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument #'.($k+1).' is not a string.');
            if(!is_dir($v))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument #'.($k+1).' is not a directory.');
            if(!is_array(static::$DirList) or !in_array($v, static::$DirList))
                static::$DirList[] = $v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes one, or more, directories from the Directory-List.
     * @throws LoaderException
     */
    public static function removeDir() {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $k => $v) {
            if(!is_string($v))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument #'.($k+1).' is not a string.');
            if(in_array($v, static::$DirList))
                unset(static::$DirList[array_search($v, static::$DirList)]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Absolute-Path for the loader, this will speed up the loading process.
     * @param string $path Absolute-Path to the Project root directory
     * @throws LoaderException
     */
    public static function setAbsPath($path = null) {
        if(isset($path)) {
            if(!is_string($path))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument is not a string.');
            if(!is_dir($path))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid path "'.$path.'".');
        }
        static::$AbsPath = $path;
    }

}
```

This is my basic autoloader i use very often, it recognizes namespaces as subdirectories and can be fed with specific directories where to search for classes.

Comment: Thanks @BrainInBlack, I used a similar approach which resulted in errors/exceptions thrown by not being able to load some obscure Wordpress classes. That's why I was asking how to "limit" the "scope" of autoloader and retain error reporting, if file/class is not found.

Thanks though, I will definitely check your autoloader namespace-wise, which is still quite alienish topic for me!

Comment: Well, as far as i know, wordpress has it's own autoloader, i.e. you have to let your autoloader just return, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: But then I would have to determine by the logic of an autoloader function when it is okay, if the file is not found and when it is not ...

And no, Wordpress does not have its autoloader, AFAIK: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21300

Comment: Just looked at the latest version of wordpress and they're not using any namespaces, i.e. you can modify your autoloader not to trigger if there is no namespace declared.

Comment: Yes, namespaces sound like a way to go. Right now, I'm trying to figure out the right approach to them which would be compatible with the Wordpress logic. I posted the question to Wordpress Stackexhange, if you're interested, check it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143400/namespacing-wordpress-project-according-to-fig-standards